# CanCan nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, rolify

I have Codes nested under Companies in my routes.

resources :companies, except: [:destroy] do
    resources :codes, except: [:destroy]
  end

Ability:

```
can :read, Company do |c|
   user.has_role? :operator, c
end

can :read, Code do |c|
  user.has_role? :operator, code.company
 end
```

My CodesController checks for

```
before_filter :set_code, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :activate, :deactivate]
  load_and_authorize_resource :except => :create #TODO fix as cancan updates
     def index
       if params[:company_id]
       ...
```

If I access /companies/1/codes, where my user shouldn't have access, I see no results. However if I try to view /companies/1 directly, I get CanCan AccessDenied.

Why doesn't this show in the nested index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also do a load_and_authorize_resource of your parent model in the codes controller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :company
```

followed by loading your code resource through your company:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :company
load_and_authorize_resource :code, through: :company
```

I don't see any added value in your before_filter, as this is exactly what CanCan will do for you...

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to accept, this works. How can I setup where /companies shows all the companies for the admin, and just the companies that belong to the user for the user?

Comment: That's something you typically set up in the ability file. By default, the admin sees everything. As you've set it up now, the user will see the companies for which he has a role 'operator'